# Register generic interface with non generic class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a generic interface in my application:

```
public interface IBaseMapper<DTO, Entity> 
    where DTO : class, new()
    where Entity : class, new()
{
    List<DTO> EntityToDTO_Transform(List<Entity> requestEntity);
    Entity DTOEntity_Transform(DTO requestDTO);
}
```

Which is being implemented by a non-generic class:

```
public class RequestMapper : IBaseMapper<RequestDTO,REQUEST>
{
    public REQUEST DTOEntity_Transform(RequestDTO requestDTO)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<RequestDTO, REQUEST>(requestDTO);
    }

    public List<RequestDTO> EntityToDTO_Transform(List<REQUEST> requestEntity)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<List<REQUEST>, List<RequestDTO>>(requestEntity);
    }
}
```

I am using `Unity` as IoC container for dependency injection.

How do I resolve dependencies?

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType(typeof(IBaseMapper<>), typeof(RequestMapper); // ???

config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is `REQUEST` meant to be changeable? If so, it needs to be a generic class. If not, just register the closed type of `IBaseMapper<RequestDTO, REQUEST>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `RequestMapper` is non-generic, you need to specify its closed-generic abstraction when making the mapping, as follows:

```
container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IBaseMapper<RequestDTO,REQUEST>), 
    typeof(RequestMapper));
```